# Flexbox children collapse in Safari

Tags: css, flexbox, safari

Flexbox children collapse in Safari but not in other browsers. Here is the minimal example ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bhL2es10/)):

```html
<html>
<body style="display: flex;height: 100vh;flex-flow: column;">
  <div style="display: flex;background: red;">
    <div style="padding: 1rem;">test</div>
  </div>
  <div style="height: 1000rem;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here we have a `div` with red background wrapping another div with some padding. There is also another flex child that is very tall (`1000rem`).

In Chrome or Firefox the result looks normal. The red flex child wraps its own child properly:

[image: Chrome]

Now in Safari it looks completely wrong (tested on Version 14.0.2 (16610.3.7.1.9)) - the second tall child causes the first one to collapse:

[image: Safari]

The red child got collapsed despite having a child. It looks like the default `min-height: auto` that is applied by the browser is being ignored in Safari.

Is there a workaround to make Safari behave according to the spec?

Comment: flex-shrink:0 to the red div?

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57044598/3597276

Comment: @TemaniAfif how come it works in other browsers? is it safe to do `* { flex-shrink: 0 }`? I need to make the whole website work

Comment: I don't think it's safe to enable shrink to all the element, you will have unwanted overflow. Simply do it for the elements where you have issues

Comment: @TemaniAfif I disagree that this question is the duplicate. I was asking "Is there a workaround to make Safari behave according to the spec?" not "What do I need to change to make it look good in Safari"

Comment: and what is the difference between both? You need to add something to your code to have the correct output and it's flex-shrink:0 ... it's a workaround and a way to make safari behave to what it's expected by the Spec

Comment: @TemaniAfif I need a global rule that will fix the whole website, because I have this issue everywhere

Comment: the rule is (like stated in the duplicate) flex-shrink:0

Comment: you just told me to not apply that rule globally

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the below code link? Hope it will work for you. We have added `flex-wrap:wrap;` in body and added `flex:1;` in its last child so it will take full width.

Please refer to this link: https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/4oh5sb3a/1/

```html
<body style="display: flex; display: -webkit-flex; height: 100vh;flex-flow: column; flex-wrap:wrap; -webkit-flex-wrap:wrap; ">
  <div style="display: flex;background: red; ">
    <div style="padding: 1rem;">test</div>
  </div>
  <div style="height: 1000rem; flex:1;"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't answer my question: "Is there a workaround to make Safari behave according to the spec?"